# Discord Bot connected to Websocket but not finished loading

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am working on a discord bot like for 2 weeks and all the time there were no problems...
but now when i was starting the bot, there is just standing this:

`1314 [main] INFO net.dv8tion.jda.api.sharding.ShardManager - Login Successful!`

`2326 [JDA [0 / 1] MainWS-ReadThread] INFO net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket`

but normally there is at least one more line with something like "finished loading" and this is not there anymore... but i dont know why

The Bot is online but nothin works (commands, etc.)

Comment: Discord just did an update where you have to register your account, maybe your auth expired

Answer (score 2):

The `new JDABuilder()` constructor has deprecated by JDA.

So you need to use [`createDefault()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#createDefault(java.lang.String)), [`createLight()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#createLight(java.lang.String)), or [`create()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#create(java.lang.String,net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent,net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent...)) methods instead of `new JDABuilder()`.

Comment: And, If you cannot use these methods, You should update JDA to latest version.

Comment: Thank you very much! Fixed the problem with the createDefault() function ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Fasmos said, You will need to use `JDA = JDABuilder.createDefault("YOUR TOKEN").build();` Instead of `new JDABuilder`, Just adding that you must add the token, nothing else ;)