# Discord JDA: GuildSetupController -> Bot can't go ready anymore

Tags: discord-jda

I have a problem, with my discord bot. I started bot after two days again but he cant get ready on any guild where he is added. The JDABuilder looks like this (Token comes from an .env File):

```
 private static void startDiscordConnection() throws LoginException, InterruptedException {
    JDA jda = new JDABuilder()
           .setToken(Config.get("TOKEN"))
           .addEventListeners(new Listener())
           .build();
   LOGGER.info("BOT IS CONNECTED");}
```

The problem is that I get following Debug lines.

[image: Code]

The guild id is not XXXXXXX... I changed it of course.
I didn't change any permission on the discord bot website. How can i get find out why its happening?

The permission code is 522304 & bot scope

If you need more informations just ask for it.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot connected to Websocket but not finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562258/discord-bot-connected-to-websocket-but-not-finished-loading)

Comment: Yeah @Minn i got help from a discord server with the same response :) thank you also