# java discord api (jda) old bot not working

Tags: java, discord

I'm using that code:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Game;

public class Main {
    static JDA jda;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDABuilder jb = new JDABuilder();
        jb.setToken("My Bot Token");
        jb.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
        jb.setGame(Game.playing("Hello"));
        //jb.setAutoReconnect(true);
        jb.addEventListener(new tl());

        try {
            jda = jb.build();
            System.out.println(jda.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and tl.java is:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.ReadyEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class tl extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onReady(ReadyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Finish Loading!");
    }
}
```

If I use old bot's token, then I got nothing. but If I use new bot's token, then I got "Finish Loading!". Was there some jda issues?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot connected to Websocket but not finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562258/discord-bot-connected-to-websocket-but-not-finished-loading)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I solved this now.