# Discord Bot doesn't answer our Commands

Tags: java, discord, bots

I made a Discord bot following a video tutorial on YouTube. I got stuck at a part where the Bot doesn't reply to the Command.

If someone out there would know how to fix this problem I would pretty appreciate that.

Here's the source code:

Night.java:

```
package ch.teraflash;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import ch.teraflash.listener.CommandListener;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.sharding.DefaultShardManagerBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.sharding.ShardManager;

public class Night {

    public ShardManager shardMan;
    
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            new Night();
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Night() throws LoginException, IllegalArgumentException {

        DefaultShardManagerBuilder builder = new DefaultShardManagerBuilder();
        builder.setToken("XXX");
        
        builder.setActivity(Activity.playing("die Nacht."));
        builder.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
                
        builder.addEventListeners(new CommandListener());
        
        shardMan = builder.build();
        System.out.println("Bot online.");
        
        shutdown();
    }
    
    public void shutdown() {
        
        new Thread(() -> {
            
            String line = "";
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    
                    if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                        if(shardMan != null) {
                            shardMan.setStatus(OnlineStatus.OFFLINE);
                            shardMan.shutdown();
                            System.out.println("Bot offline.");
                        }
                        
                        reader.close();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Use 'exit' to shutdown.");
                    }
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }).start();
    }
}
```

CommandListener.java:

```
package ch.teraflash.listener;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.ChannelType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.TextChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class CommandListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        
        String message = event.getMessage().getContentDisplay();
        
        if(event.isFromType(ChannelType.TEXT)) {
            TextChannel channel = event.getTextChannel();
                    
            //!tut arg0 arg1 arg 2 ...
            if(message.startsWith("!tut ")) {
                String[] args = message.substring(5).split(" ");
                
                if(args.length == 1) {
                    if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Hallo")) {
                        channel.sendMessage("Hallo " + event.getMember().getAsMention() + "! ").queue();
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: @f1sh sorry I reverted that, my fault. I was more worried about the fluff OP kept re-adding.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i needed to censor the Token.

Comment: @Tryit I now did that for you. Problem was that doing that you were undoing my edits.

Comment: @Tryit also consider invalidating that token. The history of the question is still visible, you can't undo that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help :) Imma remake that Token right now and sorry for re- editing your edits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot connected to Websocket but not finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562258/discord-bot-connected-to-websocket-but-not-finished-loading)

Comment: @Minn Hey, i looked up the post and on our script there isnt a "Finish loading" too. Im not really sure were i need to replace it with createDefault(). Can you maybe help me on this?

Comment: The constructor for DefaultShardManagerBuilder is deprecated in 4.2.0+ and should be replaced by the mentioned factory methods.