# How can I fix this JDA discord bot error?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have one problem with JDA, when I try to load an event to detect new messages on a Discord channel, it doesn't detect it, but it detects private messages, I don't know how I can fix this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JDA jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken("---").build();
        System.out.println("asd");
        jda.addEventListener(new Core());
    } catch (LoginException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

 // this workds and detecting private messages
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {

    if(event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("asdasdasds");

}

        //no detect public channel messages
@Override
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {

    if(event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("bsbsbsbsb");

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot connected to Websocket but not finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562258/discord-bot-connected-to-websocket-but-not-finished-loading)

Comment: No, this post its about starting the JDA bot, i have problems with events.

Comment: Your problem is identical to this, you are not starting it correctly. Please read the answer to that question. You can see this by the linked questions to that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a deprecated constructor for JDA.

You should use [`JDABuilder#createDefault()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#createDefault(java.lang.String)) or one of the other non-deprecated ways to construct JDA.

See full documentation here: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html